# Changing Spell Factors

Tags: chronicles-of-darkness-2e, mage-the-awakening-2e

To change a spell factor within a block of factors (ie - Standard or Advanced) is there reach involved or just the dice penalty?

On a related note, under common Reach effects it mentions changing the primary spell factor, does that mean if I use a Reach to change a spell from Advanced Duration to Indefinite Duration I don't take a dice penalty (assuming the primary factor is Duration)?

Example:
I'm casting Co-Location (Space 3) (which has primary spell factor Duration) as a rote (so I have 5 free Reach). If I want Potency 3 do I just take the -4 dice penalty or can/do I need to spend Reach?

With the second part of my question, if I use a reach to "change" Duration does that mean I can get a duration of 2 turns with no dice penalty? If the answer to that is yes, can I only change a single step at a time or would it be 2 reach, 1 mana (and no dice penalty) to go Standard Duration -> Advanced Duration -> Indefinite Duration?

Comment: Welcome to the site! As I'm unfamiliar with M:tA, your question may be perfectly clear, however, consider giving an example of what you're trying to do. That may help get a better answer, and should help anyone else who might have a similar question. Happy Hunting

Comment: This should probably be two separate questions, because although they both deal with Spell Factors, they address different issues.

Answer (score 2):

1. To change within a block of factors, it's just the dice penalty.
2. That's not what it means. To get to Indefinite Duration, you've got to spend two Reach, one mana, and deal somehow with the -10 Dice Penalty. To change the Primary Spell Factory means to change something from a Potency-based Spell to a Duration-based one or vice versa.
3. A Spell with Primary Spell Factor of Duration doesn't get its Potency boosted by dice penalties. If you wanted Advanced Potency for the bonus to Withstand dispelling, that would cost a reach. (Also, that rote would give you two free Reach, not five.)
4. Again, no. Spending a Reach to move from Standard to Advanced Duration means you get one scene for free. Getting to Indefinite works as described in #2.